# Bluetooth headset A2DP works, HSP/HFP not (no sound/no mic)

Tags: 12.04, sound, bluetooth

My Philips SBH9001 headset pairs fine using Ubuntu 12.04. In the audio settings it's properly detected as A2DP device and as HSP/HFP device.

Hardware: Thinkpad X230, Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, Kernel 3.6.0-030600rc3-generic (build from Ubuntu mainline repo), Bluetooth device is USB-Id 0a5c:21e6 from Broadcom, Headset is a Philips SBH9001.

Note: Kernel 3.6 rc3 is used because of a [fix for audio on the dockingstation](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commit;h=c8415a48fcb7a29889f4405d38c57db351e4b50a) that is not in any previous branches.

Playing audio in A2DP works just fine out of the box, but when switching the headset to HSP/HSP mode there is no sound nor does the microphone work.

When connecting the headset, /var/log/syslog shows:

```
Aug 25 21:32:47 x230 bluetoothd[735]: Badly formated or unrecognized command: AT+CSRSF=1,1,1,1,1,7
Aug 25 21:32:49 x230 rtkit-daemon[1879]: Successfully made thread 17091 of process 14713 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug 25 21:32:49 x230 rtkit-daemon[1879]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 25 21:32:50 x230 kernel: [ 4860.627585] input: 00:1E:7C:01:73:E1 as /devices/virtual/input/input17
```

When switching from A2DP (standard profile) to HSP/HFP:

```
Aug 25 21:34:36 x230 bluetoothd[735]: /org/bluez/735/hci0/dev_00_1E_7C_01_73_E1/fd3: fd(34) ready
Aug 25 21:34:36 x230 rtkit-daemon[1879]: Successfully made thread 17309 of process 14713 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug 25 21:34:36 x230 rtkit-daemon[1879]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 25 21:34:41 x230 bluetoothd[735]: Audio connection got disconnected
```

Any hints how to get HSP/HFP working here?

Comment: Are you able to change the profile from *"Sound Settings -> Output -> Mode"*?

Comment: Yes, switching output mode works, there is a short clicking noise to hear. But no audio in HSP/HFP after switching. Switching back to A2DP works, audio also.

Comment: I know this is old, but for the other way around (HSP working and A2DP no) see http://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- *This is a known bug* in `bluez` with the new Broadcom BCM20702A0 series adapters; yours [is one of those.](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/patch-bluetooth-add-support-bcm20702a0-0a5c-21e6-help-206245262.html) ([**see bug report**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/962082))
- The bug is rated "high", but it has not yet been fixed. You may want to add yourself to the list of people affected by the bug, and maybe post a message asking if there is any timeline on a fix.

**Other *possible* solutions:**

- Edit `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` and under `[General]`, add the line `Enable=Socket`. Restart *blueoothd* with `sudo rfkill block bluetooth && sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thx for your answer, it explains why it happens. Unfortunately the suggested workaround does not work, the described behaviour did not change at all.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't expect it to...looks like we'll just have to wait for the bug to be fixed. :(

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got an Iogear GBU521 using Ubuntu 14.04

```
lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

I created the `*.hcd` that you can download from https://www.dropbox.com/s/8md0ygdufn0h9w1/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd?dl=0
and drop it in your `/lib/firmware` folder and then reboot.

If you want to build yours here are the steps:

1. Download the driver from
   www.iogear.com/support/dm/driver/GBU521 for Windows 8.1
2. Extract the installer
3. Go to the folder
   `GBU321_421_521_Win8.1_v12.0.0.8030/Win64`
4. After [learning about the
   PID, VID and hex2hcd](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065400/comments/11), the only problem is finding the name of the
   correct `*.hex` to convert to `*.hcd`
5. The right direction is looking
   at the `bcbtums-win8x64-brcm.inf` in the same folder. There you will
   search by the last four digits of the PID (`21e8`). For this case the
   right file was `BCM20702A1_00.002.014.1315.1338.hex` (IF YOU TRY TO
   GUESS IS IMPOSSIBLE)
6. Convert the file with `hex2hcd` (see step 4)
7. Rename the file to `fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd` and place it in `/lib/firmware`
8. Reboot
9. If it is not working unplug and plug it again
10. Enjoy!

Comment: i'd like to follow the process myself but i'm having problems with the exe installer (GBU521_FW_V12.0.0.9980.exe) which appears to be an executable and not a self-extracting archive. did you use wine to run the installer and then pick the files out of somewhere? if so, where?

Comment: I see, the issue is that the installer that i used(back in 2014) was the version v12.0.0.8030 and they updated to version V12.0.0.9980. I believe that I still have at home the original disk that came in the box. Let me upload the disk to my dropbox and I let you know the link so you can download it.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of actoins finally solved that issue:

- firmware upgrade to version G2ET86WW (2.06)  http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073834
- kernel upgrade to latest stable: 3.5.0-21
- setup firmware for Broadcom bluetooth chip following https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065400

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**

Solution of problem for my ThinkPad T430

befor fix in /var/log/syslog

```
Mar 25 18:57:37 repeat-desktop kernel: [375341.740568] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
Mar 25 18:57:37 repeat-desktop kernel: [375341.740573] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
Mar 25 18:57:37 repeat-desktop kernel: [375341.741556] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
Mar 25 18:57:37 repeat-desktop kernel: [375341.741560] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd'
Mar 25 18:57:37 repeat-desktop kernel: [375341.741563] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21e6.hcd'
```

after fix

```
Mar 25 19:17:15 repeat-desktop kernel: [376519.534498] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
Mar 25 19:17:15 repeat-desktop kernel: [376519.534503] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
Mar 25 19:17:15 repeat-desktop kernel: [376519.535720] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd' Patch
```

what i did:

1. Download file for [my chip](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd) (you can search your chip [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/))
2. Copy file to /lib/firmware/brcm/

   sudo cp ~/Downloads/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
3. Restart Bluetooth

   sudo rfkill block bluetooth && sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth