# After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working

Tags: sound, 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a nice bluetooth audio receiver connect to my HiFi stereo, and I used to be able to connect it in 14.04 as a A2DP sink with nice quality.

After upgrading to 16.04, the device connects only as headset, and when trying to switch it in A2DP mode, I have this error in my syslog:

```
May 21 11:35:50 RRyS pulseaudio[6159]: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: Refused to switch profile to a2dp_sink: Not connected
```

and the quality of audio is abismal. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hope this is useful to somebody. I have lost 3 hours digging into it... I love upgrades! ;-)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are several bugs opened about this, check for example [this one (started in 15.05)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1438510) and [this other one, quite older](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1181106); the causes in general are not well understood.

Before starting modifying system files, you can also check [Bluetooth speaker no sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763539/bluetooth-speaker-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1) (seems a different bug) and [A2DP bluetooth doesn't work on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766554/a2dp-bluetooth-doesnt-work-on-16-04?rq=1) (solved in comments by a kernel upgrade).

The fix that worked for me is the following --- thanks to [user RobertFM in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1438510/comments/5) and [SimFox3 in Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1526534#p1526534). All the following instructions must be executed from a root shell (`sudo -i`). Take care and triple check.

1. First of all, make a backup of these files (you never know):

   ```
   cp /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf.bak
   cp /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/default.pa.bak
   cp /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11 /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11.bak
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` and make it similar to this one:

   ```
   # Configuration file for the audio service
   # This section contains options which are not specific to any
   # particular interface
   [General]
   Enable=Gateway,Source

   # Switch to master role for incoming connections (defaults to true)
   Master=true

   # If we want to disable support for specific services
   # Defaults to supporting all implemented services
   #Disable=Gateway,Source,Socket
   Disable=Socket

   # SCO routing. Either PCM or HCI (in which case audio is routed to/from ALSA)
   # Defaults to HCI
   #SCORouting=HCI

   # Automatically connect both A2DP and HFP/HSP profiles for incoming
   # connections. Some headsets that support both profiles will only connect the
   # other one automatically so the default setting of true is usually a good
   # idea.
   AutoConnect=true

   # Headset interface specific options (i.e. options which affect how the audio
   # service interacts with remote headset devices)
   [Headset]

   # Set to true to support HFP, false means only HSP is supported
   # Defaults to true
   HFP=true

   # Maximum number of connected HSP/HFP devices per adapter. Defaults to 1
   MaxConnected=2

   # Set to true to enable use of fast connectable mode (faster page scanning)
   # for HFP when incoming call starts. Default settings are restored after
   # call is answered or rejected. Page scan interval is much shorter and page
   # scan type changed to interlaced. Such allows faster connection initiated
   # by a headset.
   FastConnectable=true

   # Just an example of potential config options for the other interfaces
   #[A2DP]
   #SBCSources=1
   #MPEG12Sources=0
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out the line

   ```
   #load-module module-bluetooth-discover
   ```

   (you really only need to add the `#` at the start)
4. Edit `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11` and add the line `/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` after the loading of the module `module-x11-xsmp`; in practice you should edit the file near the end to have a stanza like

   ```
   if [ x"$SESSION_MANAGER" != x ] ; then
       /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp "display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER" > /dev/null
       # add this line here:
       /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
   fi
   ```
5. Reboot.

   Now you should be able to set your device to A2DP and enjoy high quality music:

   [image: Sound settings]

   Notice that sometime you need to Disconnect and Reconnect your device to re-enable A2DP:

   [image: Bluetooth devices]

   ...yes, it's a can of bugs. But when it works it works beautifully.
6. Troubles after reboot

   After all of this, sometime the trick seems to work just only after the next reboot. In such a case, try to follow [rmfought's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/811130/16395):

   > What works for me is to connect the bluetooth device, switch to
   >   HSP/HFP mode, disconnect, reconnect and then switch to A2DP mode.

   ...works for me too (again, sometime). I had to even un-pair a re-pair the dongle once.
7. If it still doesn't work...

   If this also isn't working for you, you can try with  [this script](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae) --- its author is keeping it up-to-date.

Comment: audio.conf is not present in ubuntu 16.04, only main.conf, will that work?

Comment: @JoakimKoed --- you're right, I checked --- I had a `audio.conf-remove` probably remnant from the upgrade. I simply recreated it --- so now I am in doubt, maybe just points 3 and 4 are necesssary?

Comment: Steps 3 & 4 did not fix for me, and I recreated audio.conf as per the above and no fix. Deleting the bluetooth device and repairing fixes, but doing that every time you want to use bluetooth audio is not feasible.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle sorry to hear that - here it worked (no need to re-associating) after the first time. Must be a different thing...

Comment: You are a rockstar

Comment: doesn't work for me and my Polaris V8 bluetooth speaker. no audio.conf and creating one doesn't help. Only steps 3 and 4 also don't change anything

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have an `audio.conf` but I did have an `audio.conf.dpkg-remove` so I copied that back to `audio.conf` and modified as described by Rmano.

Comment: Only partial solution. Worked the first reboot. Then turned off the headset to save battery as I was not using it, and when I reconnected the headset only get mono sound. Dropping down the menu in sound settings to select A2DP just switches back to the speakers. So it's either mono or nothing for me. It's a shame that in 2016 bluetooth support in Linux is still light years away from its competitors. I mean, even Android (a Linux per se) does this out-of-the-box...

Comment: @romanovzky --- try also [rmfought's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/811130/16395) --- fixed it to me when sometime it happens after the reboot.

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work if you have an application using sound, like youtube on a browser, vlc, etc. You seem to have to close all of them to perform the disconnect and connect trick. Any ideas on how this can be workedaround?

Comment: Brilliant! It does the trick with me! I suggest you add a reference to it in your answer, as all together seems to give a fully working solution to the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 41):

What works for me is to connect the bluetooth device, switch to HSP/HFP mode, disconnect, reconnect and then switch to A2DP mode.

Comment: Same here. However, it is not supposed to be this way and it used to work  properly in previous version.

Comment: For me too, that worked. But a real big pain in the a** for something that was working (nearly) flawlessly in 15.10 and before.

Comment: Oh believe me, I agree.  it's a huge pain.  The only distro I've found that handles BT correctly out of the box nowadays is Solus OS.

Comment: Works. But you didn't answer the question: why do all OS's suck so horribly? ffs "how to bluetooth headset?"

inb4 "you do it" nerds

Comment: This is super weird but it worked!

Comment: Holy crap. Didn't expect this to work, but it did.

Answer (score 5):

This is not necessarily a solution for those who need the mic, but this worked in Ubuntu 16.04 for me:

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
```

And then add `Disable=Headset` under `[General]`.

```
[General]
Disable=Headset
```

And restart the bluetooth service

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

And all the creds to this guy:
https://jimshaver.net/2015/03/31/going-a2dp-only-on-linux/

Comment: Unluckily, didn't work out for me. My bluetooth dock icon is greyed out… Maybe it's the driver/module? XPS 13 9350 and ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Dolanor Not sure wether this is still a problem, but a if the dock icon is greyed out, it most likely means that your bluetooth-adapter is softblocked. Try `rfkill unblock bluetooth` and maybe even `bluetoothctl` and then `power on` (in the bluetoothctl-CLI).

Comment: This worked in my case zorinos 12

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, there is no `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file. I added `Disable=Headset` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, restarted the service, reconnected my headphones, but the audio profile was by default `off`. Not sure this worked?