# Is Ubuntu 16.04 stable?

Tags: 16.04

I would like to know if it's safe to install Ubuntu 16.04 (safe as in stable, unlike 15*). If it's stable, is it possible to upgrade directly to 16.04 from 14.04 without carrying out a clean installation?

Comment: This is not opinion-based, if we use it to link to problems and their solution. Notice that for "stable" upgrade from an LTS you are supposed to wait for 16.04.1

Comment: This is not a forum. The question is not answerable. AU is not supposed to list "problems" in one Q&A.

Comment: Looks like 16.04.1 is coming up soon ([July 21, 2016](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule)). That said, I'm planning to just deploy Ubuntu 16.04 at this point.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by stable. The standard policy in Ubuntu is to offer the upgrade when the new LTS reaches .1, i.e., 16.04.1.

I upgraded my 14.04 in several machines, and I can signal these problems:

- on a wide range of machines with intel graphics, you have [a bad tearing of the screen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1554613), fixable by installing Yakkety kernels;
- on several machines, [suspend freeze the system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302);
- in some flavors (xubuntu, mate) [the cursor disappears after a lock](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604) (fixed by switching to a virtual console and back);
- [Bluetooth audio sink with high quality (A2DP) stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working) at least for some hardware;

So yes, you have to be ready for a bit of bumpy switch. On the other hand, I like 16.04; the system feels snappier than 14.04, and LibreOffice 5 is a big step forward.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple deployments over vast variety of hardware, so far very stable, no issues even with few PPA added.

Comment: Thanks. What about the upgrade process from 14.04??? I am using Ubuntu desktop version 14.04 and wish to upgrade it to 16 without a clean installation.

Comment: I would strongly recommend fresh install but if you wish to update, make sure all your PPAs are disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Stable? Depends on how you define it.  I have three workstations with it installed, I have been installing it as an AD-DC server, I have an issue with that, but only because I installed Samba manually.  No crashes so far, and no major problems that were not caused by me,  So stable, YES!!!

Unity more configurable for sure, better than the earlier versions.

One caveat: documentation, when you search for answers on it, you get a lot of older version answers, but as far as running stable.

Here is a link all about upgrading, and how to do it bt several methods.

[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you sir. what about the upgrade procedure?

Comment: It was pretty simple when I tried it, you need to go into your update manager and make a change to all versions of Ubuntu first, i had an issue with it only because it wants to update to 15 first, then it went to 16, so in that I say it had issues, at least for me.  I learned of a new command that may fix that, I foud it here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu  I hope that will help you

Comment: BTW, I install a lot of crazy stuff on my systems, so my assessment of the upgrade process is a little suspect, I did not try it on a plain vanilla 14.04 to 16 upgrade.

Comment: I tried the update manager and there is no update available. I used the terminal with the command:
do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Looks like ubuntu 16 is not available for my country. Or do i need to change setting on the update manager?
No new release found

Comment: Yeah you have to change the setting in update manager, it says tell me about all LTS updates, but it never tells you about 16.04, until you cahnge the setting to tell you about all updated OS's.

Comment: Did that. Still not available. in etc/update-manager/release i see prompt=lts. i assume it should be ok.

Comment: Upgrades won't show until 16.04.01 is released later.  You can still do it, plenty of answers already on it.