# Ubuntu 16.04 New/old bluetooth headset problem with sound

Tags: sound, 16.04, bluetooth, headset

first sorry for my simple English.

Now I try explain my problem: My bluetooth headset Philips SHB7150 not working (propably accu) and Philips service exchange it for new one. Now when I connect the new headset with other computer with windows or android, everything is fine. First pairing and connecting was good, icon my headset show up in sound menu and I can select this as sound source. I hear sound in both mode: A2DP and HSP(mono). But when I reconnect headset I don't hear any sound in any mode. Additionally when I change HSP sound mode on A2DP system automatically unselect my headset as sound source. Until after many trails only when I set sound mode in HSP before disconnecting headset and reconnect I hear sound in both sound mode.

I have different headset (Motorola S305) and this one work perfectly. I can reconnect without any problems.

Any idea why?

Can I somehow delete any info about Phillips headset in ubuntu and do fresh start?

I hope I explained my problem well.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I found this python script who seems to work for everyone.

It will disconnect the device not working, update the profile to the good parameters and reconnect the device.

It's working fine, but I'm still waiting for an update of `bluez`.

Here's the link: https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae

Let me know if you run in any troubles.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and elaborate ? "Link only" answers are discouraged.

Comment: Yes sorry done :)

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, helped me another thread on this forum https://askubuntu.com/a/820633/696715

Edit file /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and add below the [General] this:

**Disable=Headset**

and let me know if it helped.

Comment: If these are the same question so it should be flagged as duplicate, there is no need to copy and paste same answer here ;)