# How do I fix Kubuntu Bluetooth problem (by fixing source code)?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, kde

> **This is about fixing the bug by fixing the source code. I know all the workarounds. This is not a duplicate.**

I've been using Kubuntu for about year and half. Ubuntu stability and familiar KDE desktop is great and all. But connecting any bluetooth headset to work in high quality (A2DP Sink) is a nightmare. There is well known bug and no real solutions other then connect headphones set it to low quality, disconnect, connect again and set it to highquality. I've tested it on other distros and there is no such problem. (There are plenty of threads about this issue here and on other places.)

Now, I do programming for a living. Well... web programming, but I am a fast learner and this makes me so angry that I am willing to learn myself Cpp to fix this stupid bug.

I've never done any Ubuntu or KDE opensource code commisions, and I'm having problem finding how to clone repo for the KDE BT deamon. Can you point me to the right place so I can get started?

[Launchpad repo looks dead](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluedevil). [Github repo seems to be alive.](https://github.com/KDE/bluedevil) But source code commits are year old and it has no issues section, so I'am not sure this is the right code to start working on.

Ubuntu/KDE guys help me out, so I can help make Kubuntu better :)

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I have *had* the same problem and this sounds like a problem discussed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working)

Comment: The problem is in the source code of bluez or pulseaudio in Ubuntu

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks, that gets me closer.

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced a similar issue on Ubuntu 14.04.

The following worked for me

1. Turn on bluetooth on your machine, but don't connect your device
2. Run `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` from the command line. It should return a positive integer.
3. Connect to your headphones.

If the above steps alone do not resolve your problem, you can try using `blueman` instead of the default KDE utility.

1. `sudo apt-get install blueman`
2. `blueman-applet`
3. Pair your device
4. Connect to `Audio Sink`

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried this one too. But had the same issue. Blueman has easier way of setting hi/low quality but it is still a workaround. I want to fix that damn KDE daemon :D