# Connect Bose Revolve as Microphone

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

I have Bose Soundlink Revolve Bluetooth Speaker.
I am using Ubuntu 17.04.
I followed [After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working) to activate A2DP mode.

Now I can get audio from my bluetooth speaker. 
However, although there is a microphone facility attached to the speaker, I don't see it listed in input sources list in ubuntu.

what's the solution?